# Conditional Expectation for Poisson random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution

Let $X_i$ be Poisson i.i.d. random variables with $P(X=k)=e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}, \quad k=1,2,\ldots$. Let $X=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$.

Find conditional expectation
$$
E(X_1\times\cdots\times X_n\mid X=m),
$$
where $m \in R$.

Comment: $X_i$'s are independent? Please share your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that the index starts with $k=0$ (and not $k=1$)?

Comment: @drhab: yes, you are right, k=1

Comment: @StubbornAtom: the $X_i$ are not independent once we conditioning on their sum

Comment: In order to answer the question "are the $X_i$ independent?" you must provide info about the distribution of $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$. Not info about the conditional distribution $(X_1,\dots,X_n)\mid X=m$. Btw, $X$ in your question  still shows index $i=0$.

Comment: Assuming independence of $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$, and that $k$ starts from $0$ and $i$ starts from $1$, the expectation is just the unbiased estimator of $\lambda^n$ based on $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. This follows from Lehmann-Scheffe theorem.

Comment: You wrote $k=1,2,\ldots.$ But you should have $k=0,1,2,\ldots.$ It starts at $0,$ not at $1. \qquad$

Comment: @StubbornAtom : It is _an_ unbiased estimator, not _the_ unbiased estimator. That it is the "best" unbiased estimator follows from Lehmann–Scheffe assuming you've got sufficiency and completeness (which you do). But you don't need it to be the best unbiased estimator in order to answer this question. And you can show it's unbiased without either Lehmann–Scheffe or Rao–Blackwell.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Unbiased estimator based on $\sum X_i$ is unique, hence *the*. Of course you don't need any theorem to show unbiasedness, it is the connection I mentioned that uses Lehmann-Scheffe. The question still has not clarified on the independence part, which is the starting point of my comment and the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comment by StubbornAtom gives a conceptual answer.

Here is a more flat-footed one.

The distribution of $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ conditional on $X=m$ is multinomial with parameters $m$ and $(1/n,\ldots,1/n)$, which is to say
$$P\left( (X_1,\ldots,X_n)=(m_1,\ldots,m_n)\mid X=m\right) =\frac{m!}{\prod_{i=1}^n m_i!}  \prod_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{m_i}.$$
Note that the conditional expectation of $S(z_1,\ldots,z_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n z_i^{X_i}$ is (by the binomial theorem) $$T(z_1,\ldots,z_n)=E[S(z_1,\ldots,z_n)|X=m] = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {z_i} n\right)^m.$$
The desired answer is the mixed partial derivative $$\left(\prod_{i=1}^n\frac\partial{\partial z_i} \right)T(z_1,\ldots,z_n) = \frac m n \frac{m-1}n\cdots\frac{m-(n-1)} n\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {z_i} n\right)^{m-n}$$ evaluated at $z_1=\cdots=z_n=1$, namely, $m!/(m-n)!\times n^{-n}$.